# Background slide animation during onMouseMove not working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a React Login screen with black background set using CSS Styling. The login screen is quite elementary at this point which comprises of 3 input tag username, password and submit respectively.

All i am trying to do right now is change the background of the login screen with slide down effect (height 0 to height $loginScreenHeight) whenever the mouse moves.

I got it working as expected but with a slight side-effect. The side-effect is whenever the mouse moves the initial background goes away momentarily and the new background starts sliding down.

I want the new background to start sliding on top of the old background and cover it up. Can some Css expert please throw a light on what i am missing here?

Following is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { userlogin } from "./../action/userLogin";

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    passwd: "",
    loginStatus: "",
    mouseOverLogin: false
  };

  enteruname = e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  enterpasswd = e => this.setState({ passwd: e.target.value });

  submitCredentials = e => e.preventDefault();

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="login"
        onMouseMove={() => this.setState({ mouseOverLogin: true })}
      >
        <form
          onSubmit={this.submitCredentials}
          className={
            this.state.mouseOverLogin ? "loginForm animateLogin" : "loginForm"
          }
        >
          <p>Login</p>
          <hr />

          <input
            className="uname"
            placeholder="Enter Username"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.enteruname}
          />
          <input
            className="passwd"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            type="password"
            name="passwd"
            value={this.state.passwd}
            onChange={this.enterpasswd}
          />
          <button className="loginBtn">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Login);
```

CSS File:-

```
.login {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vw;
}

.loginForm {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 38vw;
  width: 27vw;
  height: 54vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.login form input {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 24vw;
  height: 6vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(42, 27, 61, 0.6);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.uname {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18vh;
}

.uname:focus,
.passwd:focus {
  background: rgba(42, 27, 61, 0.6);
}

.passwd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28vh;
}

.loginBtn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5vh;
  left: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  top: 38vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(42, 27, 61, 0.6);
  color: white;
}

.login form input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.login form p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 24vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 2vw;
}

.animateLogin {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 38vw;
  width: 27vw;
  animation: slideDown 2s 1 forwards ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
//   transition: all 280ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }

  to {
    background: $navlink;
    height: 54vh;
  }
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12vh;
  width: 24vw;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `height` change to 0 is a problem because the "old background" is set on the element with 0 `height`.

I wrote 2 POC that can help you:

```css
.a,
.b {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.a:hover {
  animation: slidebg 2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 50px 0 0 blue;
}

@keyframes slidebg {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 blue;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0 50px 0 0 blue;
  }
}

.b-bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.b span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.b:hover .b-bg {
  animation: slidebg2 2s;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes slidebg2 {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="a">link</div>

<div class="b">
  <div class="b-bg"></div>
  <span>link</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome the 2nd animation is the one i was looking for smooth and without any stutter. Thank you so much. But i do have a question,  i am not clear what following property will do. Since there is no comma between the two it means its not applying the animation do both of them. Is it some css chaining effect? .b:hover will apply the amimation once it hover over it but what about .b-bg?                                                
    .b:hover .b-bg {
           animation: slidebg2 2s;
           height: 100%;
       }

Comment: `.b:hover .b-bg` searches for a `.b-bg` element within a `.b` element with state of `hover`

Comment: Anyone looking for a detailed explanation in future of "how hovering over parent will animate the child" can peek into following link https://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/